# JNI : passing double from Java side to C++ side argument/s value incorrected

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have trouble when I call a native function with double parameters. Values are incorrected, near 0 instead of 100 for exemple.

Here the code from the java side :

```
public native void SetDouble(double d);
```

The code of the C++ side :

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_XX_XX_XX_SetDouble(JNIEnv *env, jobject    instance, jdouble d) {
          double x = d;
}
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong with that ?

The call of this function is made from an Android activity.

Thank you !!

EDIT :

It seems that the problem is that I had my activity, a Java class that wrapped the call to c++. in that case, arguments are not corecctely passed. If I call directly c++ from the activity, it is ok. Any idea why ?

I need to package the c++ and provide a wrapper to call it. I can not provide the library only since the prototype of the method is made with the caller name...

Please, can someone help me ?

Comment: This should work, the error is not in the code shown. Suggest you make a minimal test application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

Well, the application is already minimal. I have an Activity, in the OnCreate method I call the Java method "SetDouble".